# Rolling back my code to a previous commit

Tags: git, azure

I have an azure website where i'm using Visual Studio Monaco and i'm publishing my code through Git.

I need to rollback the site's code to a previous commit (a working copy) without affecting my repo (only changes the local repo AND the code)

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I cannot get the question: assuming your remote is called `liverepo`: do you want to revert the commit there (without changing your local working copy) or do you want to revert the commit in your working copy without changing `liverepo`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without making changes to the remote repository.

The best approach would be to create a new commit that fixes the changes (this could even be a revert commit).

Another approach that would require [*rewriting history*](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html) (which is not a good thing) would be to bring the repository to a previous commit:

```
git reset --hard <commit-hash>
```

to the commit you want to go (obtain the hash by doing a `$ git log`). Then you will have to do a force push:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: I already made it once, but i forgot the command and i did'nt found it on google anymore. In SVN would be a really easy task =/

Answer (score 0):

you can easily checkout any commit in the history, just do a

```
git checkout hash-number
```

You'll be in detached head mode, you could then create a new branch with it or do whatever you want, you can't though push to the same branch remotely, because it would become a non-fast-forward commit, you'll either rewrite the remote, or push to a new branch remotely.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking for is `git revert HEAD~1..HEAD` . This will rollback the commit by 1.